# How to link to a jpeg in the assets images from the rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Simple question hopefully, I have an items database in my Rails project and I am entering the data of the items through the rails console (title, descriptions and prices, that sort of thing). The hiccup for me is trying to enter a link to an image, I have tried hundreds of variations and have had no success. My jpg is in the images folder, this should be straight forward for someone in the know.

Any help? Please??

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do?  Type in the path to an image?  Are you using a setter method of an object?  If so which method?

Comment: Hi Max, Im just entering data into the Mysqlite through the rails console, like so; <Item id: 1, title: "The Title", description: "A brief description", image_url: "*what goes here?*">

Comment: Was your comment truncated there?  It looks like there should be something after "like so;".

Comment: depends if/which library you use for uploads and/or how you display image_url. insufficient info

Comment: So in the console I have tried; item.image_url = image_path("app/assets/images/my_image.jpg") & other variations

Comment: @laffan this is very frustrating as you are forcing people to try to guess at how your application is set up.  You should give the reader any necessary information to address your problem, in your question.  At the moment we are trying to almost interrogate it out of you which is quite tiresome.  For example, here you are calling the method "image_url=", presumably on an instance of the Item class.  Does this class have a "image_url" field in its database table?  If not does it define that method?  If it doesn't define the method, is it including a gem or something which gives it that method?

Comment: You don't even say what your problem is, ie do you get an error, and if so what does the error say?  Or do you just get an unexpected result?

Comment: laffan you should check this gem out: https://github.com/markevans/dragonfly

Comment: >> item
=> #<Item id: 1, title: "Railway Sleepers", description: "Blah blah blah blah blah blather blather blather e...", price: #<BigDecimal:7fc221292800,'0.25E2',9(27)>, image_url: "app/assets/images/sleeper.jpg", created_at: "2015-04-19 12:16:52", updated_at: "2015-04-20 10:13:36">

Comment: This is in my index.html.erb;
        <div class="image">
            <%= link_to (image_tag item.image_url, :style => "height:100px"), item %>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="title">
            <%= link_to item.title, item %>
        </div>

Comment: I thought this was simpler and I dont have the technical lingo down just yet. Max, image_url is the name of the string attribute (column) in the database where the image is supposed to go. My image is in "app/assets/images/my_image.jpg"

Comment: >> user           # Just a reminder about our user's attributes
=> #<User id: 1, name: "Michael Hartl", email: "mhartl@example.com",
created_at: "2014-07-24 00:57:46", updated_at: "2014-07-24 00:57:46">
>> user.email = "mhartl@example.net"
=> "mhartl@example.net" This is from Hartl's Ruby tutorial, to

Comment: ^^ he is changing the email address of the user with the id: 1, simple enough. But if it was an image he was trying to direct to from his images folder, what would the link be??

Comment: You don't even say what your problem is, ie do you get an error, and if so what does the error say? Or do you just get an unexpected result? –  Max Williams 53 mins ago < No error really, its just the link to the image is broken

Answer (score 0):

This worked in the end, so in the rails console,
To find my item;

=> item = Item.find(1)

To change the bad previous link and then to link to the image in the images folder;

=>item.image_url = "my_image.jpg"

Save it;

=>item.save